# Listen for Web Worker creation?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker, webassembly

I am trying to handle `WebAssembly` workers and filter out by URL which ones that I should terminate. However, after reading through the web worker API docs I can figure out any events that are called in the browser when created.

I tried looking at mutation observers in the DOM, but I can't figure any way to listen for the creation.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

EDIT: 
I do not know the workers. I am making a chrome extension, in which I need to scan all pages for workers and their locations (url)

Answer (score 1):

There can be some mistakes, I'm trying to describe the concept. So, the idea is that worker can notify parent that he is alive itself.

```js
// MAIN JS THREAD

const worker = new Worker('url/to/your/worke.js')

worker.onmessage = message => {
  if (message === 'online') {
    // do something 
    return
  }

  // here can be your code that handles main response of the worker
}

// WORKER.js

postMessage('online')

// here you can evaluate some highload code
// that you didn't want to block maon thread

postMessage('result of highload code')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however in this case I am not the creator of the worker. Therefore I cannot handle the onmessage event. I am making a chrome extension that can handle workers on all pages.